# Is there any use for trivial objects gathered in Baldur's Gate 3?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I'm grabbing lots of seemingly trivial objects like cutlery, ropes, tongs and cups. Do they serve any purpose other than dumping them on traders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some rare occasions you do need specific items:

- A shovel is quite useful, as you will discover early on.
- Certain items can be used to play with your pets, should you happen to pick some of those up along the way ("roleplay"/fun effect only).
- Certain plain, unenchanted weapons can be used in crafting during act 1.
- You can give certain specific items as a gift to a special someone (a dialogue will trigger when you find one and have the option).
- Smoke-powder items, wine kegs, water kegs etc have certain uses mainly in combat.
- A lot of somewhat unexpected items can be used as camp supplies, but in that case they will say so if you examine them.

Comment: Can you explain who the "special someone" is? You can use spoiler tags if you don't want to reveal it.

Comment: @Stevoisiak The person(s) you might have initiated a more intimate relationship with. (a not-very-spoilery example is a statue of Shar you can give to Shadowheart).

Comment: @Stevoisiak Well supposedly all of the companions can be romanced no matter gender. During some dialog they might hint of some favourite. If you are romancing Shadowheart, she likes night orchids. If you are romancing Minthara, she likes you to butcher a bunch of innocent thieflings just because you can. Different partners, different preferences :)